# File.SaveAs stopped working: The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, shared-directory

I've been using the following code to save files to a local shared directory for a long time:

```
file.SaveAs("\\localhost\MySharedDirectory\MySubDirectory\File.docx");
```

Today, it stopped working and started throwing the error: `The specified network name is no longer available.` I can't remember making any changes to my project or computer that would cause this to happen. Any advice for things I can check to get this working again?

**Troubleshooting Details**

- I'm using the above code in an ASP.NET MVC website running on IIS 7.5. I'm using impersonation and
  confirmed that the impersonation user has (full) permission to the share,
  and also to the directory.
- In the `SaveAs(...)` file path string, I tried replacing `localhost` with `MyMachineName` and `127.0.0.1` and continued to receive the same error.
- In Windows Explorer, if I right click the directory and go into `Properties > Sharing`, the `Network Path` name to the share is:
  `\\MyMachineName\MySharedDirectory`. If I navigate to this path directly in Windows Explorer, I get the same error that my code produces.
  However, if I navigate to `\\MyMachineName` in Windows Explorer, the
  share is showing up correctly as `MySharedDirectory`, but trying to access it produces the same error.
- When browsing `\\MyMachineName` in Windows Explorer, several of my other shares
  appear, as expected, but they all generate the same error when I try to access them.
- I do not have a firewall or anti virus software running.
- Windows Update has not run or installed anything recently.

**Full Error Details**

*Message*

```
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

*Source*

```
mscorlib
```

*Stack Trace*

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename)
   at System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper.SaveAs(String filename)
   at ****.Web.Areas.Services.Controllers.****Controller.Submit1(****ViewModel model, Nullable`1 captchaValid, String action) in C:\Projects\****\****\Controllers\****Controller.cs:line 883
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: Have you restarted your computer to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted but continue to receive the error.

Comment: "If I navigate to this path directly in Windows Explorer, I get the same error that my code produces" this does not sound like a programming problem.

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development." I would recommend trying a different stack exchange site to troubleshoot the issue with the network name not being available first.

Answer (score 1):

I found a strange `Schannel` error in the event viewer which made me think to double check that the port for a recent website I added on my machine was a safe one to use. Turns out it wasn't. I was running it on port 445, which is used for file and printer sharing. I changed the port and I can access the shares again.